# Are there multiple shop_money currency in shopify?

Tags: shopify

at current_total_price_set it shows that shop_money is in "CAD", but in line item's of the same order object it shows that shop_money is in "USD" !
i am confused here ! why do they are not same currency ?

**The object is from shopify official doc, https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-04/resources/order#resource-object**

```
"current_total_price": "10.00",
  "current_total_price_set": {
    "current_total_price_set": {
      "shop_money": {
        "amount": "30.00",
        "currency_code": "CAD"
      },
      "presentment_money": {
        "amount": "20.00",
        "currency_code": "EUR"
      }
    }
  },

"line_items": [
    {
      "price": "199.99",
      "price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "199.99",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "173.30",
          "currency_code": "EUR"
        }
      },
      
    }
  ],
```